# Subversion username and last modified date in Java file

Tags: svn

When the user checks-in a Java file, I have a requirement to update the Subversion username and file's last modified date in the Java file (comments section at the top of the file). Can anyone please provide references or subversion tags for the same?

Comment: @zerkms +1 for reference to WOYAR.

Comment: Thanks. The only poor SO user is one that doesn't do anything about it after having it pointed out to them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).